# Quarkus profiles not working properly during test execution

Tags: testing, quarkus, profile

I'm encountering an issue with Quarkus profiles not functioning as expected during test execution. Specifically, when running tests using the command mvn failsafe:integration-test -Pit -Dquarkus.profile=it, the application seems to be ignoring the properties specified in application-it.properties and instead using the properties from application.properties.

Here's a simplified version of my project structure:

```
project-root
  |-- src
       |-- main
            |-- resources
                  |-- application.properties
                  |-- application-it.properties
       |-- test
            |-- java
            |-- resources
                  |-- application-it.propertie
```

In my pom.xml, I have set up the failsafe plugin and profile as follows:

```
<profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.profile>it</quarkus.profile>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

I'm using the command below to run the integration tests:

`mvn failsafe:integration-test -Pit -Dquarkus.profile=it`

Despite specifying the -Dquarkus.profile=it option and having the application-it.properties file in the appropriate location, it seems like the application is still picking up properties from application.properties during test execution.

What could be causing this behavior and how can I ensure that my tests use the properties specified in application-it.properties when running with the it profile? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to define the profile properties in the file application.properties using the syntax %profile.property. However, the properties with different profiles were ignored.

Comment: Afaik, the src/test/resources is not scanned for profiles. You should put all your files in src/main/resources or in a /config folder relative to your application.jar file.

Comment: For %test profile I believe it is scanned. You could take a look at my comment, there is info about that. Hope I was helpful 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to read this [section](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#profile-in-the-property-name:%7E:text=A%20profile%20aware%20file%20is%20only%20loaded%20if%20the%20unprofiled%20application.properties%20is%20also%20available%20in%20the%20same%20location%20and%20the%20file%20extension%20matches%20between%20the%20files.%20This%20is%20required%20to%20keep%20a%20consistent%20loading%20order%20and%20pair%20all%20the%20resources%20together.) on quarkus docs.
It says that

> A profile aware file is only loaded if the unprofiled application.properties is also available in the same location and the file extension matches between the files. This is required to keep a consistent loading order and pair all the resources together.

So you might want to add `application.properties` on the tests->resources folder and see if it might identify the properties.

Hope it helps